# Using Enums in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

I have an enum as follows:

```
enum Keys : uint
{
  Key1 = 0x01,
  Key2 = 0x02,
  Key3 = 0x05
}
```

I am trying to populate a combobox with these options using the following code:

```
cboKeys.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys));
```

I am serializing the selected value to save to disk, the problem I'm having is selecting the value from the combobox when loading the form again.  I feel like I've tried a bunch of different ways that I've found on online, but nothing works. I'm using this code to set the SelectedValue:

```
public void SetKey(Keys key)
{
  cboKeys.SelectedValue = key;
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated as I have no idea what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the an enum value in a `ComboBox`, use `SelectedItem`. For example:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
comboBox1.SelectedItem = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
```

Comment: You are right, I had to make same other adjustments, because I realized that the value was getting set, but then overwritten by the bindings because of the order of execution.  Thank You.